# Include ALL pdf graphics in document

Tags: graphics, programming

I have several plots saved as .pdf in a folder and I would like to know if there is a way of adding all of them in a document at once, without typing the path to each file.

Comment: short answer no, longer answer, if you are prepared to allow latex to escape to the shell and run system commands, and don't mind your document being system dependent you could get it to run ls *.pdf(or whatever is needed) and construct the list. (or you could just do this before starting latex)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is best to do this externally to latex (although you can use the shell-escape (write18) feature to execute the commands from within latex if you want.

I'll assume bash syntax but other command line systems can do similar.

Suppose you have a directory/folder `img` with three pdf files

```
$ ls img
a.pdf  b.pdf  other.pdf
```

and you want to include them in alphabetic order (or any other order you can achieve by using arguments to `ls` or some other command)

then executing

```
ls img/*.pdf | sed -e "s/.*/\\\\includegraphics{\\0}/" > img/imglist.tex
```

would leave a file `img/imglist.tex` that looks like

```
\includegraphics{img/a.pdf}
\includegraphics{img/b.pdf}
\includegraphics{img/other.pdf}
```

so you just need `\input{img/imglist}` in your main file, and arrange to regenerate `imglist.tex` every time you update the image directory (or every time you run latex).

Comment: Could you explain how `sed` works? It gave me zeros like so `\includegraphics{0}` instead of filenames (on macOS 10.15.1). I ended up just putting the unaltered filenames into a file, so your solution still worked fine.

Comment: @BadAtLaTeXProgramming `sed` is a stream editor. Here we use it for its regex search and replace potential. In quotation marks you can read `s/match/replacewith/`, and the `\0` in theory refers to the zero-th match (being `.*`, that is every character, as many times as possible). You got 0 because your version of `sed` interpreted 0 as a literal character, and not the matched group 0 (which you wanted to be your filenames).

Comment: as @mazunki said, the difference is probably in the shell you are using rather than sed itself, I would have tested that with bash but the number of `\\\\ ` you need, and whether you need to quote the `{}`  depends on the shell, typing regular expressions on the commandline when the shell wants to use the same special characters can be an adventure.

Comment: For reference, it's nice to know that even `"` (doble quotation) versus `'` (single quotation) marks make a difference in Bash, which is what many use. Usually, double marks means Bash should work with the string inside, while single marks are plain text from Bash' point of view. Test this: Assign a variable (`export variable=hello`) and run `echo "$variable"` and `echo '$variable'`.

Comment: I had the same problem (on macOS 13.1) with the output being just `\includegraphics{0}` for every file. A quick skim of the man file for `sed` showed that I could use an `&` for the replacement. The following `sed` command worked for me... replace the `\\0` with `&` like so:
`sed -e "s/.*/\\\\includegraphics{&}/"`

Answer (score 3):

With texlive 2024 you can access all the files without using explict scripting or `--shell-escape`.

The `l3sys-query` tool is allowed to be called in the default, restricted shell escape, mode so you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,l3sys-query}
\begin{document}

\QueryFiles{img/*.pdf}
{\begin{center}\includegraphics{#1}\end{center}}

\end{document}
```