# Insert all the images at once of a specific folder

Tags: graphics, floats, multiple-files, includegraphics

I would like to insert in my latex document almost 100 Fotos (at once), which are inside a folder, but if it is possible, just with few commands.

Now, I wont like to use:

`begin{figure}>includegraphics{folder/figure001.jpg}>end{figure}` then again
`begin{figure}>includegraphics{folder/figure002.jpg}>end{figure}` and so on until `figure100.jpg`.

Is there a easy way to write a command that takes all the images of a specific folder and insert all of them on the .tex document?

Thanks and greetings.

Comment: do your real files have consistent names like that varying by number? if so it is easy to loop in latex, if it is just a directory with a hundred files you need to use ls or dir or some such oerating system command to get the file list then again you can loop through the list in latex

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, Mr Carlisle, but what do you mean with "ls or dir"?
and the name files not always are varying by numbers. I though about a loop, whit the foor statment and range. That what you mean, right?

PS: thanks to Sebastiano for the editing

Comment: @DerHeckenritter `ls` (Mac/Linux) or `dir` are command line commands to list the files in a  folder.  Depending on how the files are named it would probably be easier to create a script to generate the LaTeX and then just `\input` that into your document.  If the files have a consistent numerical naming scheme, then a LaTeX loop is simple to do.  What OS are you using? (Mac/Windows/Linux)?

Comment: if your files are really called file01, file02, ...file100 you can generate the image  names in latex, but if the files are apple.png orange,png banana.png then you can not do it just in latex you need to get a list of files from the operating system which is the `ls` command in linux and the `dir` command in windows.

Comment: Ok. I understand.
My OS is windows. so I will search about dir.
Thanks for the help to everyone !!!.

Comment: this example uses unix/linux commands rather than windows but it is essentially a duplicate question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161114/1090