# Add markdown files recursively

Tags: pdftex, luatex, markdown, recursion

I'm trying to figure out how one could input markdown files recursively. I'm using the markdown package and it does allow inputting files with `/markdownInput`. This works for the moment but in my writing process I often switch the order of sections (creative thinking :P). If this happens I have to rename the files and also fix the markdownInput in my thesis.tex.

Right now I'm using the pdflatex compiler because it is the "default" of my university document class. As far as I understand I could write my own function in Lua to do that if I'd use the LuaLatex compiler. I did try to switch to the lualatex compiler but it throws a lot of error messages. Because of that I try to stay away from changing it.

Is there also a way to do that with pdflatex?

My structure of my thesis is

```
/chapter01/00_index.md
/chapter01/01_research_objective.md
/chapter01/02_research method.md
/chapter02/00_index.md
/chapter02/01_theory_of_world_domination.md
thesis.tex
```

It would be great to have a recursive function to add all files recursively to the document. So that I only have to maintain the order of the folders and files.

Comment: just run a command such as `find . -name \*.md > files.tex`  before you run pdflatex then you can process that list of files easily in tex (similar commands are available on windows)

Comment: this is finding all graphics to include rather than all markdown but is essentially the same: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161111/include-all-pdf-graphics-in-document/161114#161114

Comment: If you can spend some time figuring how it works (not too much), `bookdown`  is exactly what you are asking for (and yes, that you have to use  your university LaTeX class --- or any  other --- is not a problem.)

Answer (score 1):

Credits to David Carlisle :)

I created `toc.sh` which gets executed before latexmk.
As I'm using the Latex-Workshop extension for VSCode, I had to put a time check in the script otherwise latexmk is in loop.

thesis.tex:

```
\begin{document}
\input{toc.tex}
\end{document}
...
```

toc.sh:

```
# Create only toc.tex if it's older than 3 seconds
if test `find "toc.tex" -mmin +0.05`
then
    find . -name \*.md | sed -e "s/.*/\\\\markdownInput{\\0}/" | sort > toc.tex
fi
```

settings.json:

```
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
    {
      "name": "Generate TOC from files & latexmk",
      "tools": [
        "toc",
        "latexmk"
      ]
    }
  ],
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
    {
      "args": [
        "--shell-escape",
        "-interaction=nonstopmode",
        "-file-line-error",
        "-pdf",
        "%DOC%"
      ],
      "command": "latexmk",
      "name": "latexmk"
    },
    {
      "command": "./toc.sh",
      "name": "toc"
    }
  ],
```