Insert text if pictures in a certain folder exists
my code is the following
\documentclass[ngerman,german,14pt,twoside,openany]{scrbook} %Bei Hochformat [oneside] zusätzlich eintragen und linker Rand 3cm, 2 Spalten und 6cm Bildhöhe
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[cam,width=216truemm,height=303truemm,center]{crop} %Beschnittzugabe; https://komascript.de/node/786
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usepackage{pgffor} % \foreach


\begin{document}


This is just text as part of a test... This is just text as part of a test...This is just text as part of a test... This is just text as part of a test...

\begin{center}
   \foreach \s in {1,...,1000}{%
   \IfFileExists{D:/folder1/folder2/pupil\s.jpg}%
 {\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \def\ig{%
   \includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{D:/folder1/folder2/pupil\s.jpg}}%
 \node [inner sep=0pt](mypicture) at (0,0) {\phantom{\ig}};%
 \clip[rounded corners=4mm] ($(mypicture.south west)+(1mm,1mm)$) rectangle ($(mypicture.north east)-(1mm,1mm)$);%
 \node[inner sep=0pt](mypicture) at (0,0) {\ig};%
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{2mm}
}}
\end{center}

\end{document} 

Here is my question: I am working on a report for a school. In this report approximately 50 pupils will get a text with some photos. Is it possible to modify my code in such a way that the text only appears when the picture "folder 2" contains pictures, otherwise no text should appear. How can this be done? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

actually pehaps you just want to move the text inside the loop and  have \ifnum\s=1  This is just text as part of a test... This is just text as part of a test...This is just text as part of a test... This is just text as part of a test... \fi so it only appears at most once

You can move the preamble text in to the loop guarded by s=1 and \IfFileExists so that it only appears once if the loop iterates at all and does not appear if there are no files.
\documentclass[ngerman,german,14pt,twoside,openany]{scrbook} %Bei Hochformat [oneside] zusätzlich eintragen und linker Rand 3cm, 2 Spalten und 6cm Bildhöhe
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[cam,width=216truemm,height=303truemm,center]{crop} %Beschnittzugabe; https://komascript.de/node/786
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usepackage{pgffor} % \foreach


\begin{document}


\begin{center}
  \foreach \s in {1,...,10}{%


   \IfFileExists{D:/folder1/folder2/pupil\s.jpg}%
   {%
    \ifnum\s=1   
\parbox{\textwidth}{This is just text as part of a test... This is just text as part of a test...This is just text as part of a test... This is just text as part of a test...}
\fi
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \def\ig{%
   \includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{D:/folder1/folder2/pupil\s.jpg}}%
 \node [inner sep=0pt](mypicture) at (0,0) {\phantom{\ig}};%
 \clip[rounded corners=4mm] ($(mypicture.south west)+(1mm,1mm)$) rectangle ($(mypicture.north east)-(1mm,1mm)$);%
 \node[inner sep=0pt](mypicture) at (0,0) {\ig};%
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{2mm}
}}
\end{center}

\end{document} 


A very big thank you for your help, this is what I was looking for!!!!

@mario1000 note the other answer will be much faster than checking 1000 files that  are not there (I changed this answer to 10 just  so it stops quicker) l3sys-query uses Lua to get a file list

sorry if this question is a little bit late but I used your code with great success until now. As long as I have a number of s=1 (e.g. pupil1.jpg, see code above) everything works very nice. But in case I have to delete picture no. 1, i.e. the list starts with pupil2.jpg or any other number all other pictures are missing as well. I tried to change the code to "\ifnum\s>0" but without success. Would you please be so kind to gimme a hint how to solve my dilemma or should I ask a new question to the forum?

the ifnum 1 test is just for a leading paragraph as far as I can see this will include all images starting at 2 if 1 is not there

these days I would use l3sys-query @mario1000 so you can list the files in the directory and loop over them directly

@mario1000 https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714433/1090

@mario1000 oh I just noticed I posted another answer below when we released that.

thanks a lot for your prompt help!

With a current Texlive or miktex you can use the l3sys-query package (part of the core latex tools bundle) then use
\QueryFilesTF{*.jpg}{\node....\includegraphics{#1}}{}{No Files found}


@rallg yes, and allowed without --shell-escape as it is in the default "safe" list of allowed programs in both texlive and miktex
